# Can my component name be "Date" while still allowing me to access built-in "new Date()"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, next.js

I'm going through the [NextJS tutorial](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/dynamic-routes/polishing-post-page) right now, but with my own twist. In the NextJS example the custom component is called "Date" (/components/date.js) but NO built-in Date() object is being used in processing - so the Date component name is not colliding with anything... it's unique to the file.

However in my case, my component is called "Date" just like in the tutorial... but I also want to use JS built-in "Date object" in the same file during processing (so i have 2 Dates present). It seems when I do "new Date()" now and try to call just the built-in Date object... the component function is getting called instead so it throws error.

**I know I can simply re-name my Date to PublishedDate and references to "<PublishedDate>" instead and it work just fine then.**

**But I wanna know for learning purposes** is there a way to have my own component re-use a built-in name i.e Date... is there a way around it that's valid? This is more of a curiosity question so I can properly learn the JS/React/NextJS and understand WHY/WHY-NOT with respect to JS/NextJS/React internals (otherwise I would have just changed the name and be done with it).

**date.js**

```
import { format, parse } from "date-fns"

export default function Date({ dateString }) {
  const date = parse(dateString, "LLLL d, yyyy", new Date()) // call built-in Date()????
  return <time dateTime={dateString}>{format(date, "LLLL d, yyyy")}</time>
}
```

**Error thrown:**

```
import { format, parse } from "date-fns"
  2 | 
> 3 | export default function Date({ dateString }) {
    |                               ^
  4 |   const date = parse(dateString, "LLLL d, yyyy", new Date())
  5 |   return <time dateTime={dateString}>{format(date, "LLLL d, yyyy")}</time>
  6 | }
node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:762
error - components/date.js (3:31) @ new Date
node_modules/next/dist/build/output/log.js:33
[31merror[39m - TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'dateString' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.
    at new Date (/Users/cfork/projects/nextjs-blog/components/date.js:3:32)
    at Date (/Users/cfork/projects/nextjs-blog/components/date.js:4:50)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `Date` inside a `function Date(…) {…}` will always resolve to just that function. You need two distinct names to refer to the two separate things.

- One option would be to export an anonymous function declaration, removing the name:

  ```
  export default function({ dateString }) {
  //                    ^^
    const date = parse(dateString, "LLLL d, yyyy", new Date())
    return <time dateTime={dateString}>{format(date, "LLLL d, yyyy")}</time>
  }
  ```
- another option would be to refer to the global `Date` not via a variable, but as a property of the [global object](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#global):

  ```
  export default function Date({ dateString }) {
    const date = parse(dateString, "LLLL d, yyyy", new global.Date())
    //                                                 ^^^^^^^
    return <time dateTime={dateString}>{format(date, "LLLL d, yyyy")}</time>
  }
  ```
- If the `.name` of the function is important, use some aliases:

  ```
  const GlobalDate = Date;
  const DateComponent = function Date({ dateString }) {
    const date = parse(dateString, "LLLL d, yyyy", new GlobalDate())
    return <time dateTime={dateString}>{format(date, "LLLL d, yyyy")}</time>
  }
  export { DateComponent as default }
  ```

You can also change the name of the function to something else, like `DateComponent` or nothing, without changing the names in the other modules under which you import the function. The export is named `default`, that's all what matters for the other modules.

However, it is in general a bad idea to name things the same as standard globals, it leads to confusing code that will be hard to understand for all developers, yourself included.

Comment: "*…it is in general a bad idea to name things the same as standard globals*" is about all that needed to be said.

Comment: i agree @Bergi learned a lot from your post real quick (coming from backend statically typed languages land and learning JS w/Typescript/Python/maybe later Rust)

Ended up just calling my component something meaningful as it was the easiest/trivial solution to go with "PublishedDate". Here is the end result, nothing fancy. 
https://github.com/snazzybytes/satoshi-vibes/blob/b012d65b28a4a2b5194a5b0b96dd19dd52c968f8/components/publishedDate.tsx#L8

i like your option of an "alias" , didn't know about the syntax allowing for "new global.Date()" thanks!

https://www.satoshivibes.com/

Answer (score 1):

Javascript will not allow you to use an inbuilt function as a custom function.
Did you try changing the name of the function and try again?

Comment: Yea I'm cooking now when I change the name to PublishedDate... then all is well when using Date.

But still being new in JS land, I just wanted to know if it's just an all out no-no.

When you say "will not allow you to use an inbuilt function as a custom function".... you mean to say you can't name your components the same name as the built-in javascript special objects like Date... because then it will be confused which constructor to use (is there no way like in kotlin for example you can specify full package like com.kotlin.Date() and it will use that)

Comment: From my experience so far, JavaScipt doesn't allow it. However, if you don't want the code to be confusing in case the application is huge, you can name the function in a camel case format including the date. For example instead of "function Date()", you can say "function appDate()".

Comment: Agreed, as previously mentioned "PublishedDate" camelCase was already decided! But again.. since I'm just starting to learn about V8 engine I had to ask the question and rule out the stuff I know from "other langs"